# z-index not working with placing image in front of video

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Whenever I try to add in an image in front of the video, it doesn't work. Whenever I try to add in a z-index: -1 to the video to put it behind the photo, it disappears behind the background, but whenever I add a z-index: 1 to the image, nothing changes.Here's the code I have for it, don't worry, I plan on using a stylesheet instead of inlining it.

```
<img src="http://www.marcuswhelan.com/wp-content/themes/inforlinx-theme/images/authorNew.png" alt="" style="z-index: 1;" />
<div style="float: left; width: 45%; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 165px; margin-top:     375px; position: absolute;">
<div id="evp-317be98d6cf250cd9af6366444e778ec-wrap" class="evp-video-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

Here's also the url for the page: http://www.marcuswhelan.com/

Thanks for any help at all.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a greater z-index value to the image and a lower z-index value to the video.
For example: 
Image value - 2
Video value - 1